# Open Source SQL/Code Injection Scanning Application?

Tags: sql-injection

I have a site that I see is getting a ton of SQL injections and Code injections per day. I use CrawlTrack to view/record/block the IPs, but now I want to do a comprehensive scan of my domain to see if I am overlooking any vulnerabilities I need to be fixing AsAP.

Does anyone know of any stand alone Mac application or browser based scanning software that would help find potential issues on a domain?

Answer (score 0):

Acunetix has a [free edition](http://www.acunetix.com/cross-site-scripting/scanner.htm). Check if it is useful. [Here is a OWASP XSS](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) prevention reference. It has reusable components, cheat sheets etc.

Answer (score 0):

Does your database support stored procedures? This would help prevent the SQL injection issues.

Comment: if the MYSQL server is greater than 5.0 then it would, I have MySQL - 5.0.45.

Comment: Do you have anything preventing you from using stored procedures, then?